# How to SKIP one out of every five cells in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am pulling quarterly financial data and I am wondering if there is a function that will allow me to pull data in while skipping the annual data that occurs every fifth cell. I have seen some suggestions to use offset, but I cannot see how that does anything other than pull in the data from every fifth cell that I am hoping to exclude. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of skipping cells, consider adding based on row names.  For example, if the fifth row was always named "Annual," you could use the following formula.  =SUMIFS(A1:A10,"<>Annual",B1:B10 (For purposes of example, I've assumed label (e.g. Q1, Q2, etc. are in Column A and the values you want to add are in Col. B.  You can deal with more complicated labels by using functions like "FIND" in the Criteria.)

Comment: Hi @National Champs2020 ,, check my post I've solved the issue, and I'm sure it work for U. ☺

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your periods (quarters, years) are in column A and the quarterly values are indicated by Q1, Q2 etc, and that column B contains the amounts. You can try in column C the formula:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="Q",B2,"")
```

Drag it to fill the other cells.

It checks if the cell in column A starts with Q. If yes, it copies the content of the corresponding row in column B.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

*Since OP has not provided the Source data, therefore I've assumed data set, and used method which calculates `year wise quarterly total` and skips every `5th cell, which is Year Total`.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put Quarter Value in Column F as shown.
- Formula in cell `G16`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((ROUNDUP(MONTH($A$16:$A$47)/3,0)=MID(F16,2,1)*1)*(YEAR(A$16:A$47)=RIGHT(F16,4)*1)*($B$16:$B$47)),"")
  ```

---

**Edited:**

*In case if you want to generated period of each quarter in column F with Year Total then you need to use these formulas.*

- Formula in cell D16:

  ```
  ="Q"&INT((MONTH(A16)-1)/3)+1&" "&YEAR(A16)
  ```
- Now this formula in cell F16:

  ```
  =IF(MOD(ROW(),5)=0,"Year Total:",IFERROR(INDEX($D$16:$D$47,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($I$15:I15,$D$16:$D$47),0)),""))
  ```

[image]

---

**N.B.**

- Since source table doesn't have data for Q3 & Q4 in year 2020, so that the formula returns ZERO in cells G23 & G24.
- You may adjust quarter values in column F, as well as cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the raw data doesn't have usable text labels that distinguish a data row from a total row, then add a 'flag' column: `=MOD(ROW(B2),5)<>0` will provide a TRUE/FALSE flag that autofilter and pivottable can filter on.